# Python 2.4 - unittest: TypeError: run() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, unit-testing, typeerror

I can't quite figure this one out, the following code works perfectly with Python 2.6+

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(TestMrdfWriter("testParParser"))
    suite.addTest(TestMrdfWriter("testMrdfWriter"))
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite())
```

With Python 2.4 however I get the following error

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./src/TestMrdfWriter.py",
> line 42, in ?
>     unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite())   File "/home/producer/python2.4/lib/python2.4/unittest.py", line 428, in
> __call__
>     return self.run(*args, **kwds) TypeError: run() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the code works in Python2.6 either. It should be

```
unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

without the parentheses after `suite`.

Comment: thanks that was the problem, hmmm strange it worked ok when running it through the PyDev eclipse module